# Send email via Office 365 with MFA enabled and App Passwords disabled

Tags: smtp, office365, multi-factor-authentication

Our application currently supports sending emails via SMTP. We have some customers who have enabled MFA and managed to get it working by setting an App Password which we use when sending the email via SMTP.

We have another customer who has MFA enabled and has also **disabled the use of App Passwords**. Given that we cannot use app passwords and MFA is enabled, is it possible to send via SMTP or is there another way of potentially sending using the API that works with MFA?